# Replace string value from JSON to a List

Tags: python, json, list

I have a similar Json structure:

```
{
    "test": [
        {
            "name1": "tap",
            "name2": "Tik; eev; asdv; asdfa; sadf"
        },
        {
            "name1": "Pap",
            "name2": "Tik; eev; asdv; asdfa; sadf"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want the `value` of the key `name2` to be a list. For example:

The `value` `"Tik; eev; asdv; asdfa; sadf"` replaced with `['Tik', ' eev', ' asdv', ' asdfa', ' sadf']`

This is what I have done but I can't update the json into new one.

```
import json

with open('testJson.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for x in data['test']:
    string = x['name2']
    my_list = string.split(";")
    string = my_list


with open('testdata.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

When I open the `testdata.json` its the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the split list back to the data. In your code, you are just discarding it. You're treating `x['name2']` like a reference to a string rather than a string value. You can't assign it to another variable and expect that to be reflected in the data structure- you need to explicitly update the data structure with the new value.

```py
import json

with open('testJson.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for x in data['test']:
    string = x['name2']
    my_list = string.split(";")
    x['name2'] = my_list


with open('testdata.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Comment: Do you also know how to append the `name1` value into the `name2` array?

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
string = ingredient['name2']
[...]
string = my_list
```

you're getting the string without the context it was in. - `string` is just a name that stores some contents, it doesn't link back to the `ingredient` dictionary.

You need to change the final line here to `ingredient['name2'] = my_list` so that you change the insides of the dictionary, not some local string. ;)